# if fall through

Tags: haskell

What's the Haskell equivalent pattern for if fall through in imperative languages, like:

```
function f (arg, result) {
    if (arg % 2 == 0) {
     result += "a"
    }

    if (arg % 3 == 0) {
     result += "b"
    }

    if (arg % 5 == 0) {
     result += "c"
    }

    return result
}
```

Comment: You could use the State monad to do this

Comment: Answers to this question will be muddied.  You are asking about a series of if constructs but embedded in your example is mutable memory, which is a very different beast in Haskell.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of using the `State` monad, you can also use the `Writer` monad and take advantage of `String`'s `Monoid` instance (really `[a]`'s `Monoid` instance):

```
import Control.Monad.Writer

f :: Int -> String -> String
f arg result = execWriter $ do
    tell result
    when (arg `mod` 2 == 0) $ tell "a"
    when (arg `mod` 3 == 0) $ tell "b"
    when (arg `mod` 5 == 0) $ tell "c"
```

Which I think is pretty succinct, clean, and simple.

---

One advantage this has over the `State` monad is that you can rearrange order in which concatenations happen by just rearranging the lines.  So for example, if you wanted to run `f 30 "test"` and get out `"atestbc"`, all you have to do is swap the first two lines of the `do`:

```
f arg result = execWriter $ do
    when (arg `mod` 2 == 0) $ tell "a"
    tell result
    when (arg `mod` 3 == 0) $ tell "b"
    when (arg `mod` 5 == 0) $ tell "c"
```

Whereas in the `State` monad you'd have to change the operation:

```
f arg = execState $ do
    when (arg `mod` 2 == 0) $ modify ("a" ++)
    when (arg `mod` 3 == 0) $ modify (++ "b")
    when (arg `mod` 5 == 0) $ modify (++ "c")
```

So instead of having a relationship between execution order and order in the output string, you have to examine the actual operations closely (there's a subtle difference between `(++ "a")` and `("a" ++)`), while the `Writer` code is very clear at first glance in my opinion.

---

As @JohnL has pointed out, this is not exactly an efficient solution since concatenation on Haskell `Strings` is not very fast, but you could pretty easily use `Text` and `Builder` to get around this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Text.Lazy (Text)
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Builder as B
import Control.Monad.Writer

f :: Int -> Text -> Text
f arg result = B.toLazyText . execWriter $ do
    tellText result
    when (arg `mod` 2 == 0) $ tellText "a"
    when (arg `mod` 3 == 0) $ tellText "b"
    when (arg `mod` 5 == 0) $ tellText "c"
    where tellText = tell . B.fromLazyText
```

And so there's no real change to the algorithm other than conversion to more efficient types.

Comment: Lovely use of `Writer`!

Comment: @luqui: the code looks nice but the performance won't scale.  I'd probably prefer writing to an `Endo String`.  Or if the OP wants to use `Text` instead of `String`, a `Builder`.  This is why writing high-performance Haskell gets a bad rep...

Comment: @JohnL This is a problem with Haskell lists and the default `String` type, not with the algorithm.  You could pretty easily switch to using `Text` and `Builder` since `Builder` implements `Monoid` as well.

Comment: @JohnL See my edits for how to do this with `Text` and `Builder`.  There's no real change to the code, so I don't see how this has anything to do with how it's difficult to write high performance code with Haskell in this scenario, other than having to know about `Text` and `Builder`.  The problem that using `Builder` avoids is also present in imperative languages, since linked lists are not unique to Haskell.  It all comes down to what data structure you're choosing to work with, and Haskell certainly lets you change structures more easily than more traditional languages.

Comment: if I add another condition that if `arg mod 7 == 0` then replace the result to "d", would this solution still be valid? I don't know how to that in Writer, but in State, you just modify it with `const "d"`.

Comment: @bheklilr: my point about performance is twofold: as you surmise, it's necessary to know about `Text` and `Builder`.  In this regard Haskell is worse than many other languages since very few languages have made the mistake of implementing a `String` via a linked list.  The other issue I have in mind is related, but perhaps more subtle: we show code like yours (which is clean & elegant) to beginners, and it works fine at first.  But when it doesn't scale, they think Haskell doesn't perform well.  IMHO we should use scalable solutions even for the simple cases (esp. when it's so simple, as here)

Comment: @Sawyer: you could still use a Writer, but you'd need to change to a more complicated monoid.  Doing so has some advantages over operating with State; in particular monoids are trivial to use in parallel/concurrent settings.

Answer (score 10):

The function can be written quite succinctly, provided that we're willing to somewhat obscure the logic of the original imperative version:

```
f :: Int -> String -> String
f arg = (++ [c | (c, n) <- zip "abc" [2, 3, 5], mod arg n == 0])
```

Monad comprehensions can reproduce the original logic nicely:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MonadComprehensions #-}

import Data.Maybe
import Data.Monoid

f :: Int -> String -> String
f arg res = maybe res (res++) $
        ["a" | mod arg 2 == 0]
    <>  ["b" | mod arg 3 == 0]
    <>  ["c" | mod arg 5 == 0]
```

However, it isn't a very commonly used language extension. Luckily for us (hat tip to  Ørjan Johansen in the comments), there is already built-in comprehension sugar for the list monad, which we can also use here:

```
f :: Int -> String -> String
f arg res = res ++ 
        ['a' | mod arg 2 == 0]
    ++  ['b' | mod arg 3 == 0]
    ++  ['c' | mod arg 5 == 0]
```

Comment: Actually ordinary list comprehensions will work similarly to your monad comprehensions as well: `f arg res = res ++ ['a' | mod arg 2 == 0] ++ ['b' | mod arg 3 == 0] ++ ['c' | mod arg 5 == 0]`

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, uh, I completely forgot (even though I personally abused this trick a few times). I'll include this in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Using the State monad as Jan Dvorak's comment suggested:

```
import Control.Monad.State

f :: Int -> String -> String
f arg = execState $ do
  when (arg `mod` 2 == 0) $ modify (++ "a")
  when (arg `mod` 3 == 0) $ modify (++ "b")
  when (arg `mod` 5 == 0) $ modify (++ "c")
```

Comment: I suggest using the Writer monad instead, with `tell` instead of `modify . flip (++)`.

Answer (score 6):

I think the short answer is that the approach to fallthrough in Haskell is `Monoids`. Whenever you want to combine many things into one thing, think `Monoids`. Addition is a great example:

1 + 2 + 4 + 0 + 3 = 10.

When adding numbers, theres sort of a no-op value `0`. You can always add it and it won't change the result. Monoids generalize this concept, and Haskell calls the no-op value `mempty`. This is how you drop items out of your combination (in your example, you're dropping the values that don't divide evenly). `+` is the combiner. Haskell calls it `mappend`. There's a shorthand symbol for it: `<>`.

Multiplication is a Monoid, and the `mempty` value is `1`, the combiner is `*`.

Strings are also a Monoid. The `mempty` value is `""`, the combiner is `++`;

So here's a very simple implementation of your function using Monoids:

```
import Data.Monoid

f :: Int -> String -> String
f arg str = str <> modsBy 2 "a" <> modsBy 3 "b" <> modsBy 5 "c"
  where
    modsBy n v = if arg `mod` n == 0 then v else mempty
```

The neat thing is that since Monoids generalize the concept, you can generalize this function pretty easily so it builds up any Monoid, not just a string. You can for instance pass in a list of divisor, monoid pairs, and some initial monoid to start with, and whenever the divisor divides evenly, you add the monoid:

```
f :: Monoid a => Int -> a -> [(Int, a)] -> a
f arg initial pairs = initial <> mconcat (map modsBy pairs)
  where
    modsBy (n, v) = if arg `mod` n == 0 then v else mempty
```

`mconcat` just combines a list of Monoids together.

So your initial example could now be run like:

```
> f 10 "foo" [(2,"a"), (3,"b"), (5,"c")]
"fooac"
```

But you could just as easily build up a number:

```
> f 10 1 [(2,1), (3,2), (5,3)]
5
```

One of the great things about Haskell is it captures and generalizes a lot of concepts I didn't even realize were there. `Monoids` come in really handy, and whole app architectures can be built on them.

Answer (score 5):

There's quite a few ways to do this. One thing you could do is represent each `if` as a function from `Int -> Maybe Char` and then concatenate a list of `Maybe Char` into the final string:

```
maybeMod :: Int -> a -> Int -> Maybe a
maybeMod d v i = if i `mod` d == 0 then Just v else Nothing

f :: Int -> String
f i = mapMaybe ($ i) [maybeMod 2 'a', maybeMod 3 'b', maybeMod 5 'c']
```

Comment: I'd go for `Int -> a -> Int -> [a]` so that I can use `++` (or `concat`) instead of `catMaybes`

Comment: You can use `mapMaybe` instead of `catMaybes $ map`.

Answer (score 4):

IMO you should tackle this different entirely. You're testing a series of very similar conditions; those should be kept together, not spread over a bunch of conditionals with no obvious relation. Why not put them in a list! Because each mod option should trigger another signal character you want an *association list*. So you start with `[(2,'a'),(3,'b'),(5,'c')]`. (if it's more of these, e.g. 10, use `take 10 $ zip primes ['a'..]`, with a list of all prime numbers!)

Now we need, for each of the entries, to decide: if the given number is divisable by the prime, return the character, else don't add anything. That's a very succinct list comprehension:

```
f :: Int -> String
f arg = [ signal | (signal, n) <- [(2,'a'),(3,'b'),(5,'c')]
                 , arg `mod` n == 0                         ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import Control.Arrow

f :: Int -> String -> String
f arg = (if arg `mod` 2 == 0 then (++"a") else id) >>>
        (if arg `mod` 3 == 0 then (++"b") else id) >>>
        (if arg `mod` 5 == 0 then (++"c") else id)
```

In this case, `>>>` is just `flip (.)`.